# Calling server side inner function from client side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a playing card that is displayed using a cardCreateNode method for displaying the card image. I have this card.js file on the server side. After dealing cards, I want the client to display the images of the cards using the card.createNode method the client file is global.js. But I get the error "createNode is not a function.

The card.js file on Node.js server
//The card

```
    function Card(rank, suit) {

      this.rank = rank;
      this.suit = suit;

      this.toString   = cardToString;
      this.createNode = cardCreateNode;
    }
```

//DIV node for card display

```
    function cardCreateNode() {

      var cardNode, frontNode, indexNode, 
      spotNode, tempNode, textNode;
      var indexStr, indexStrB, spotChar, 
      backNode;

     // This is the main node, a DIV tag.

      cardNode = 
      document.createElement("DIV");
      cardNode.className = "card";

      // Build the back of the card
      backNode = 
      document.createElement("DIV");
      backNode.setAttribute("style", 
      "background-color:red; font- 
      size:2em;");
      backNode.className = "back";

     // Build the front of card.

      frontNode = 
      document.createElement("DIV");
      frontNode.className = "front";

     // Get proper character for card suit 
     and change font color if necessary.

      spotChar = "\u00a0";
      switch (this.suit) {
      case "C" :
      spotChar = "\u2663";
      break;
      case "D" :
      frontNode.className += " red";
      spotChar = "\u2666";
      break;
      case "H" :
      frontNode.className += " red";
      spotChar = "\u2665";
      break;
      case "S" :
      spotChar = "\u2660";
      break;
     }

     // Create and add the index (rank) to 
     the upper-left corner of the card.

     indexStr = this.rank;
     if (this.toString() == "")
     indexStr = "\u00a0";
     spotNode = 
     document.createElement("DIV");
     spotNode.className = "index";
     textNode = 
     document.createTextNode(indexStr);
     spotNode.appendChild(textNode);
     spotNode.appendChild
     (document.createElement("BR"));
     textNode = 
     document.createTextNode(spotChar);
     spotNode.appendChild(textNode);
     frontNode.appendChild(spotNode);

    // Create and add the index (rank) to 
     the bottom-right corner of the card.

     indexStrB = this.rank;
     if (this.toString() == "")
     indexStrB = "\u00a0";
     spotNode = 
     document.createElement("DIV");
     spotNode.className = "bottomindex";
     textNode = 
     document.createTextNode(indexStrB);
     spotNode.appendChild(textNode);
     spotNode.appendChild
     (document.createElement("BR"));
     textNode = 
     document.createTextNode(spotChar);
     spotNode.appendChild(textNode);
     frontNode.appendChild(spotNode);

    // Create and add spots based on card 
    rank (Ace thru 10).

     spotNode = 
     document.createElement("DIV");
     textNode = 
     document.createTextNode(spotChar);
     spotNode.appendChild(textNode);
     if (this.rank == "A") {
     spotNode.className = "ace";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     }
     if (this.rank == "3" || this.rank == 
     "5" || this.rank == "9") {
     spotNode.className = "spotB3";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     }
     if (this.rank == "3") {
     spotNode.className = "spotB1";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     }
     if (this.rank == "3") {
     spotNode.className = "spotB5";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     }
     if (this.rank == "4" || this.rank == 
     "5" || this.rank == "6" ||
     this.rank == "7" || this.rank == "8" 
     || this.rank == "9" ||
     this.rank == "10") {
     spotNode.className = "spotA1";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     spotNode.className = "spotA5";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     spotNode.className = "spotC1";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     spotNode.className = "spotC5";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
    }
     if (this.rank == "6" || this.rank == 
     "7" || this.rank == "8") {
     spotNode.className = "spotA3";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     spotNode.className = "spotC3";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     }
     if (this.rank == "7" || this.rank == 
     "8" || this.rank == "10") {
     spotNode.className = "spotB2";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     }
     if (this.rank == "8" || this.rank == 
     "10") {
     spotNode.className = "spotB4";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     }
     if (this.rank == "9" || this.rank == 
     "10") {
     spotNode.className = "spotA2";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     spotNode.className = "spotA4";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     spotNode.className = "spotC2";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     spotNode.className = "spotC4";
     tempNode = spotNode.cloneNode(true);
     frontNode.appendChild(tempNode);
     }

     // Add front node to the card node.

     cardNode.appendChild(frontNode);
     // Add Back node to the card node.

      cardNode.appendChild(backNode);

     // Return the card node.

      return cardNode;
     }
```

On the server side I deal the cards to players
and then send a socket request to the client to display the cards that were dealt.

```
     //gameController.js
      socket.on('deal', function() {
        var gbaguduGame = 
        tables[socket.room];
        gbaguduGame.deal();
        var gameData = {};
        gameData.players = 
        gbaguduGame.players;
        io.to(socket.room).emit('dealt', 
        gameData);
  });
```

On the client side in the global.js file I have this code

```
     socket.on('dealt', function(gameData) {

    for(var i=0; i<Object.keys(gameData.players).length; i++) {

      for(var n=0; n < gameData.players[Object.keys(gameData.players)[i]].cardsHand.length; n++) {
        var whom = gameData.players[Object.keys(gameData.players)[i]];
        console.log("The whom in gamedata players: " + JSON.stringify(whom));
        whom.cardsNode = whom.seat + "Cards";
        var node = whom.cardsHand[n].createNode();
        node.setAttribute("id", "card" + n);
        node.firstChild.style.visibility = "hidden";
        whom.cardsNode.appendChild(node);
      }
    };
  });
```

I get error in var node = whom.cardsHand[n].createNode(); as it says createNode is not a function. How can I call the create node function in the Card object from the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var node = whom.cardsHand[n].createNode();
```

did not work because the client could not access functions on the server.(I believe this is a security feature). It can access other attributes of the card as below;
    var node = whom.cardsHand[n].rank;
//or
`var node = whom.cardsHand[n].suit;
but it cannot access the 
        var node = whom.cardsHand[n].toString; 
or 
        var node = whom.cardsHand[n].createNode(); 
as these are functions.

The work around and answer to my question was to move the cardCreateNode function to the client side, as it can and will only be used on the client side for rendering the card image to the client.

Hope I've not wasted your time and this is somehow useful!! thanks.